# Set up IntelliJ route with remote server

Tags: intellij-idea, ssh

I am trying to connect to an ssh network (call it 2nd ssh), that I connect after having connected to another ssh through an ip address. The project in IntelliJ (2020.3.3 Community Edition) is from github, and I was wondering whether there is a way to connect Intellij with the 2nd ssh. So instead of connecting to the 2nd ssh through the windows terminal, and having to commit - push - pull whenever I make changes in IntelliJ, is there a way to work on IntelliJ and connect it with the 2nd ssh so I can run things there more quickly?

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest looking at the [JetBrains Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html), you may also need to set up an ssh proxy.

Comment: I did see that, but there is no File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment option in version 2020.3.3.

Comment: apologies, I'm on macOS at the minute, I'm not sure how much help I can be debugging a windows install.

Comment: This option is available in Ultimate Edition only.